# Multiprocessing initially returns None

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm currently writing a program that utilizes the multiprocessing tool in Python.

When I try to return the result from the function that utilizes multiprocessing, and then print it, it will first attempt to print it and prints `None`.  However, once it runs through the multiprocessing function and process, it will print again with the valid answers.  This is odd, and I have figured out a way around it, but I'm curious as to if someone has a solid answer to why this happens.

Below is the function I use for multiprocessing.

```
def ParallelProc:

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        core = 7

        p = mp.Pool(core)
        solutions = p.map(calc, NEW_IC)

        return solutions
```

Then I try to run it and set it to a variable, and print it like below

```
sol = ParallelProc()
print sol
```

My only guess is that it runs the multiprocessing in the background and moves the code forward, trying to print with nothing returned yet.  Then once `ParallelProc` converges, it starts again from that point.

This is an easy work around seen below

```
sol = ParallelProc()
if sol != None:
    print sol
```

Any ideas as to what is going on?

FYI I'm  running this code through the windows command prompt.

Comment: The code you posted won't run. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__': Should not be put inside a function. Its purpose is to avoid running code when importing a module. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do . As Blender said, can you post a working minimal example so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Please post your actual code and the exception you are seeing. Seeing what you have, I would expect a `SyntaxError`.